# In Transact Sql, stored procedure doesn't return the right result

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have one StoredProcedure

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[NewsSelect]
    @Name nchar(40)=null,
    @PublishDate date=null, 
    @SearchStringName nchar(100)=null,
    @Sort char(1)='1',
    @Order bit=1,
    @startRowIndex int = 1,
    @pageSize int = 25,
    @TotalRecords int Output

AS
begin
set rowcount @pageSize;

With newsSelect(ID, Name, PublishDate, [Status],RowNumber) as(
  select
        ID, 
        Name,
        PublishDate, 
        [Status],
        RowNumber
    from
        (select
ROW_NUMBER() over(order by  
    case when @Sort = '1' and @Order=1 then News.Name end asc,
    case when @Sort = '1' and @Order=0 then News.Name end desc,
    case when @Sort = '2' and @Order=1 then News.PublishDate end asc,
    case when @Sort = '2' and @Order=0 then News.PublishDate end desc,
    case when @Sort = '3' and @Order=1 then News.[Status] end asc,
    case when @Sort = '3' and @Order=0 then News.[Status] end desc)as RowNumber,                    
                News.ID,
                        News.Name as Name, 
                        News.PublishDate,
                        News.[Status]

                        from [News]
where (@SearchStringName is null or(@SearchStringName is not null and ( Name like '%'+@SearchStringName+'%' )))
       group by News.ID, News.Name, News.PublishDate,News.[Status]) as temp)
select * from newsSelect where newsSelect.rowNumber> @startRowIndex;

With newsSelect1(ID,  Name,  PublishDate,  [Status],RowNumber) as(  select
        ID, 
        Name,
        PublishDate, 
        [Status],
        RowNumber
    from
        (select
        ROW_NUMBER() over(order by  
            case when @Sort = '1' and @Order=1 then News.Name end asc,
            case when @Sort = '1' and @Order=0 then News.Name end desc,
            case when @Sort = '2' and @Order=1 then News.PublishDate end asc,
            case when @Sort = '2' and @Order=0 then News.PublishDate end desc,
            case when @Sort = '3' and @Order=1 then News.[Status] end asc,
            case when @Sort = '3' and @Order=0 then News.[Status] end desc)as RowNumber,                    
                News.ID,
                        News.Name as Name, 
                        News.PublishDate,
                        News.[Status]

    from News
   where (@SearchStringName is null or(@SearchStringName is not null and ( Name like '%'+@SearchStringName+'%' )))
     group by News.ID, News.Name, News.PublishDate,News.[Status]) as temp)          

            select @TotalRecords = Count(*) from newsSelect1



END
```

When I tried to select from table manually with "like"

```
USE [tableName]
GO

SELECT [ID]
      ,[Name]

  FROM [dbo].[News]
  where News.[Name] like '%'+ 'te' +'%'
GO
```

result return 2 rows

```
21  Test 1
22  Test 3
```

but when I test store procedure

```
USE [tableName]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int,
        @TotalRecords int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[NewsSelect]
        @Name = NULL,
        @PublishDate = NULL,
        @SearchStringName = N'te',
        @Sort = NULL,
        @Order = NULL,
        @startRowIndex = 0,
        @pageSize = 25,
        @TotalRecords = @TotalRecords OUTPUT

SELECT  @TotalRecords as N'@TotalRecords'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

it return 0
where is the problem ? why it don't return 2 rows?

Comment: Don't name your stored procedure `SELECT` ... also the stored procedure is `SELECT` but you attempt to execute `NewsSelect` so I'm a bit confused

Comment: What happens if you run the actual CTE as a standalone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem

```
 @SearchStringName nchar(100)=null
```

when I change type from **nchar** to **nvarchar** it work OK :)

Comment: Yes, `nchar(100)` means that it's always 100 characters long, so the `like` was searching for a `te` padded with 98 spaces :)

Answer (score 0):

you set @TotalRecords

```
SELECT  @TotalRecords as N'@TotalRecords'
```

but use @return_value

```
SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

perhaps you meant ?

```
 SELECT  'Return Value' = @TotalRecords
```

Comment: I changed but is also 0